# Is there some event/method before all emit calls in Socket.IO?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a lot of data sending through `Socket.IO` and in some cases I need to check if a particular object is sent to the browser before? So is there some method or event which is before any `emit` calls in which I could run double check and in certain cases stop the send process? Some sort of middleware...

Answer (score 0):

No, socket.io correctly expects you to handle any checks before emitting an event. There shouldn't be a situation where you've done your checks, you're ready to emit an event, and then something changed right after you emitted the event.

With async and socket.io, if you emit events in the correct order (if you have a sequence of events, the previous event should trigger the next one), your situation shouldn't happen.

I'd suggest restructuring your code and taking a second look at it. If you still want to do what you're asking however, you can write a wrapper function myEmit() that takes socket.io's emit() and adds a few checks.

Whether you overwrite socket.io's emit() or just call myEmit() is up to you *(pst, don't do it)*.

Comment: The main problem is that I have about 10 files/classes which parses data from several sources and gives the user a single list. Each class consists of several methods each of which has 2-3 `request` with nested callback. SO basically I need to to the data check in each class before emit instead of checking one before emit...